Cannot Call to Amazon Connect flows with phone numbers claimed already
I have claimed 3 phone numbers and assigned each to different flows. I tried to make call to all three claimed numbers through softphone but none of the numbers are directing to the assigned flows and instead soft dialer shows error that it cannot be connected, in logs it says "Cannot dial third party destination". I have also enabled outbound calling.
I am attaching the images and logs for reference. Belows is CCP logs that shows it fail to connect due to third party number.
Logs:
       "objects": [
            {
                "request": {
                    "event": "api_request",
                    "requestId": "1712259267220-mf1o5ka3d1f",
                    "method": "createOutboundContact",
                    "params": {
                        "endpoint": {
                            "endpointARN": null,
                            "type": "phone_number",
                            "name": null,
                            "phoneNumber": "[redacted]",
                            "agentLogin": null,
                            "queue": null
                        },
                        "queueARN": "arn:aws:connect:ca-central-1:975050249873:instance/ab203524-228f-408c-9562-850e417dbbfd/queue/3957f9e8-fc2d-4fa4-866d-a1bc78bd20e5"
                    }
                },
                "response": {
                    "event": "api_response",
                    "requestId": "1712259267220-mf1o5ka3d1f",
                    "data": null,
                    "err": "{\"type\":\"UnauthorizedException\",\"message\":\"Cannot dial third party destination: Unauthorized service call.\",\"stack\":[\"UnauthorizedException: Cannot dial third party destination: Unauthorized service call.\",\"    at constructor.extractError (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:115996)\",\ "    at constructor.callListeners (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:144312)\",\ "    at constructor.emit (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:144022)\",\ "    at constructor.emitEvent (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:137702)\",\ "    at constructor.e (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:133219)\",\ "    at n.runTo (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:171189)\",\ "    at https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:171395\",\ "    at constructor.<anonymous> (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:133489)\",\ "    at constructor.<anonymous> (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:137758)\",\ "    at constructor.callListeners (https://nps-prototype.my.connect.aws/shared-worker/connect-engine.js:2:144418)\"],\"retryStatus\":\"none\",\"statusCode\":400 }"
                }
            }
        ],
        "line": 151,
        "agentResourceId": "d7072e7d-5857-4da0-93ee-732a154eb7b6",
        "loggerId": "1712259247324-v1msjycpxw",
        "contextLayer": "SharedWorker"
    },
    {
        "component": "ccp",
        "level": "TRACE",
        "text": "AWSClient: <-- Operation 'createOutboundContact' failed: {\"message\":\"Cannot dial third party destination: Unauthorized service call.\",\"code\":\"UnauthorizedException\",\"time\":\"2024-04-04T19:34:27.331Z\",\"requestId\":\"d573abfe-b3d9-4e68-954f-0a0285a4bcbd\",\"statusCode\":400,\"retryable\":false,\"retryDelay\":85.52718557901568}",
        "time": "2024-04-04T19:34:27.332Z",
        "tabId": null,
        "exception": null,
        "objects": [],
        "line": 0,
        "agentResourceId": "d7072e7d-5857-4da0-93ee-732a154eb7b6",
        "loggerId": "1712259247324-v1msjycpxw",
        "contextLayer": "SharedWorker"
    },


Each outbound call needs to be associated with a caller ID. I guess the problem is that Amazon Connect can’t find one to associate with the outbound call. Caller ID is usually set on the queue level (docs). Try to create a new queue; set a caller ID on this queue; attach the queue to the agent’s routing profile.
